# Slow in opening videos on iPod Touch

Tags: ios, video, performance

I have an iPod Touch 3G 64GB with 4.3.3, and, with just 5 videos loaded i get a problem with this symptoms:

- When I tap Videos, it takes ages to load, crashes, then I can load again, still slow
- Every video has the same preview thumbnail, taken from a genius playlist
- When playing a video, I tap on it, the menu appears after several seconds. I press pause, the video will stop playing after 10 seconds
- If a video has closed captions, will show a subtitle every 3 sentences (slow)
- No problems at all with Music/podcast/books/apps

I tried to remove all videos but even with no videos, the video app continues to crash
This behaviour started from day one, not happened suddenly

What i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating to iOS 5.1.1 fixed the problem